# Allow access based on a domain name (Apache)?

Tags: apache-2.4

**CONTEXT**

I am running an Apache/2.4.38 (Debian) Server.
Here are my

**/var/www/html/.htaccess**

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Content"
AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

and
my
**/etc/apache2/apache2.conf**

```
<Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Require all granted
</Directory>
```

When using this, users have to enter a login and password to access the website. All fine !

And when I use  `AllowOverride None`, nobody has to enter anything.

```
<Directory /var/www/>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride None
                Require all granted
</Directory>
```

**QUESTION**

How can I allow access from a certain IP (or domain name) such that users do not have to enter login/pass ? Ideally, I would like to allow access from a certain domain (https://mxtoolbox.com/SuperTool.aspx?action=a%3abiosoft-ipcms.fr&run=toolpage) only.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of splitting your configuration between the server config and a .htaccess file, it would be easier to maintain and faster to execute if you kept it all in the server config. Then you could put the following in your server config:

```
<Directory /var/www>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/html>
  AuthType Basic
  AuthName "Restricted Content"
  AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
  <RequireAny>
    Require valid-user 
    Require ip ...
  </RequireAny>
</Directory>
```

where you would insert the IP address of the source host you want to allow. If you want to allow requests from just a certain referrer URL, you could also add something like

```
Require expr "%{HTTP_REFERER} == ..."
```

But realize that the requestor can set the Referer header to any value they want, so this is insecure.

See the docs for [Require](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require), [RequireAny](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#requireany), and [Expressions](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html).